# Wifi keeps on dropping in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, network-manager, realtek-wireless

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and I am having issues with my wifi. Every five the connection drops in my laptop(it shows that it is connected to the network but the internet connection is not there) and I have to run the command repeatedly

```
sudo killall NetworkManager
```

repeatedly to get the internet to work. Does any body have any idea why it keeps on happening and what is the permanent solution for this problem. Please note it is a issue with my ubuntu laptop only, internet works fine in other devices.

Edit

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev 01)
```

Comment: It may be related to the driver. Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lspci -nn | grep 0280` Thanks.

Comment: @chili555 please see the output in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Drivers in linux kernel for this adapter are not very good.

Download [THIS FILE](https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/rtlwifi-new-dkms_0.5_all.deb)

Also [linux-firmware](https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/linux-firmware_1.144%2Bar3012_all.deb) should be updated for 12.04.

Copy it to your home folder and run

sudo dpkg -i rtlwifi-new-dkms_0.5_all.deb

If there are no errors, reboot.

Comment: Encountered this error on runnign ERROR (dkms apport): unable to determine source package for rtlwifi-new-dkms

Comment: What is your kernel version? `uname -r` ?

Comment: 3.2.0-29-generic

Comment: Your kernel is too old. I suggest upgrading it by running `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-trusty` then reboot and try again.

Comment: I tested the package, it installs OK.