# Wifi keeps on dropping in Ubuntu 12.04, how to uninstall update

Tags: 12.04, networking, dpkg, intel-wireless

As per [Wifi keeps on dropping in Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636044/wifi-keeps-on-dropping-in-ubuntu-12-04), I followed the instructions: Copy it to your home folder and run `sudo dpkg -i rtlwifi-new-dkms_0.5_all.deb` .
Having done that to *3.13.0-70*, my connect speeds have dropped from 150 Mb/s to a max of 72 Mb/s and Internet speeds as well.

How do I uninstall the package? I did find out after the fact, that I have an Intel wireless card. Did not think Realtek driver would affect it as it has.

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall it by running

```
sudo dpkg -r rtlwifi-new-dkms
```

But if you have an Intel adapter, this package does not affect it in any way.

Comment: I was under that impression, but could not explain the drop in reported speed. I just used Synaptic to uninstall, but as you said, it should not affect. It is a Lenovo Z50 laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Having gone through the network, the connect speed issue was network hardware and not Ubuntu 12.04. A WiFi a/p was at fault which cleared after a hard reset. Package was removed through Synaptic rather than command line.